# How to use SmartyStreets LiveAddress Plugin with dynamically loaded form

Tags: javascript, wordpress, smartystreets

I am trying to get the [LiveAddress website plugin](https://smartystreets.com/docs/plugin) to work in a Wordpress website. The form is loaded dynamically via javascript.

It seems that the form is not visible to the plugin at the time the plugin loads.

The plugin shows the following message in the javascript console:

*NOTICE: No matches found for selector #field_96764599. Skipping...*

The form I am trying to use is generated by Podio (podio.com), but I have tried the same without success using a form hosted by jotform.com. If I copy the HTML of the form and paste it on the page, it works. The problem happens when the form is loaded via javascript.

Can someone see what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

```
<!-- BEGIN Podio web form -->
<script src="https://podio.com/webforms/12651261/927644.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  _podioWebForm.render("927644")
</script>
<noscript>
  <a href="https://podio.com/webforms/12651261/927644" target="_blank">Please fill out the form</a>
</noscript>
  <div class="podio-webform-container">
  A webform by <a href="https://company.podio.com/collaboration-software" class="podio-webform-inner">Podio</a>
  </div>
<!-- END Podio web form -->
<script src="//d79i1fxsrar4t.cloudfront.net/jquery.liveaddress/2.8/jquery.liveaddress.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var ss = jQuery.LiveAddress({
    key: 'HERE IS WHERE I PUT MY KEY',
    waitForStreet: true, 
    debug: true,
    addresses: [{
        street: '#field_96764599'
    }]
});
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow :)

Comment: @pedro did you ever solved this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a bit late but have you tried using .ready() with jQuery?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $( document ).ready(function() {

        var ss = jQuery.LiveAddress({
        key: 'HERE IS WHERE I PUT MY KEY',
        waitForStreet: true, 
        debug: true,
        addresses: [{
            street: '#field_96764599'
        }]

      })

    });
```

Comment: This is probably the best answer. In addition you can look at this example http://jsfiddle.net/pitcrew/v1vzb4eg/ on modal usage that can apply to this case as well. You have to make sure that the plugin is either instantiated or reactivated or remapped after the form is added to the page